# How to ignore certain packages on "navigate to class" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to have IntelliJ ignore certain packages when using the "Navigate Class" dialog for Java? There are loads of classes that pop up there which I rarely want to look at and even am explicitly am forbidden to use - like the `com.sun.*` classes. It'd be nice if they become invisible unless explicitly requested.

Comment: Not possible without explicitly excluding the files/folders, see also: [IDEA-107386](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107386)

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't filter/ignore in the 'navigate to class' dialog you can exclude classes from completion and auto import:

[image]

Perhaps this is helpful for you in different ways.